# Microsoft teams chat reading in python

Tags: python, microsoft-teams

I came up with the idea to make a python script that reads a Microsoft Teams chat and checks it for new messages, so I won't forget my homework, but I can't find a way to read the chat in the first place. Could someone push me in a right direction?

Comment: Do they have an API for this?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Galviger - Could you please share that you have to read first chat in list of chat or first message in Chat?

Answer (score 1):

You can use below graph API for list chat

```
GET /me/chats
GET /users/{user-id | user-principal-name}/chats
GET /chats
```

For getting first chat you can use **$top** OData query parameter

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/chats?$top=1
```

Referrence Document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chat-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http